# jquery promise and typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript, promise

Got the project from other developers, they have it correctly compiled, I have a bug in typescript on line "return deferred.promise()".

Type 'JQueryPromise<{}>' is not assignable to type 'JQueryPromise'.

```
export function promise<T>(resolver: (resolve: (data: T) => void, reject: (error: any) => void) => void): JQueryPromise<T> {
    const deferred = $.Deferred();
    resolver(
        data => {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        },
        ex => {
            deferred.reject(ex);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

there are a lot of such errors, so I think the problem is not in the code but in some configuration, what could be the matter?

Comment: What is the `@types/jquery` version you're using? I can't reproduce the error on fresh install.

Comment: jquery.d.ts: Type definitions for jQuery 1.10.x / 2.0.x

Comment: I'm asking about the exact version of package, as stated in `package.json`.

Comment: <package id="jQuery" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />

Comment: id="jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="2.8.8"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you just need to pass the proper type to the `Deferred` factory. This code compiles:

```
export function promise<T>(resolver: (resolve: (data: T) => void, reject: (error: any) => void) => void): JQueryPromise<T> {
    const deferred = $.Deferred<T>(); // here we used generic type for Deferred
    resolver(
        data => {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        },
        ex => {
            deferred.reject(ex);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

I can't be sure, although, whether this problem is interfering with .NET specifics.

Answer (score 0):

For code that doesn't use generics, I had almost the same error message, but instead of

Type 'JQueryPromise<{}>' is not assignable to type 'JQueryPromise'

it said

Type 'JQueryPromise<{}>' is not assignable to type 'IAccountSettings'.

where IAccountSettings is obviously my type, or in this case, an interface. Building on Cerberus' excellent answer above, I changed the declaration of the deferred by just putting in the specific type:

```
public get(): JQueryPromise<IAccountSettings> {
var deferred = $.Deferred<IAccountSettings>();
```